# Как выводить записи в JSON по убыванию?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Нужно чтобы записи прилетали по убыванию(скрин 1)
Т.е. - сейчас = "1", "2", должно быть "2", "1".
Сделал такую штуку(скрин 2), но записи все равно прилетают по возрастанию.
Как реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
for ($i = 2; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $authorID = $posts["Posts"][$i]["author_id"] = $i;
    $posts["Posts"][$i]["author_avatar"] = $i;
}
```

Comment: добавьте в запрос `ORDER BY post_id DESC`

Comment: а у меня же по post_id достается запись. т.е. два условия: owner_id и post_id, а post_id равен $i

Comment: Ваша проблема не относится ни к php ни к JSON

Comment: а к чему? как добиться желаемого результата?

Answer (score 0):

Вы просматриваете объект javascript в консоли браузера.
В javascript порядок ключей объекта не гарантирован.

```js
const o = {};

for(let i=5; i>0; i--) {
  o[i] = {id: i};
}

console.log(o);
```

Если Вам нужен порядок - используйте массив.

```js
const o = {};
const keys = [];

for(let i=5; i>0; i--) {
  keys.push(i);
  o[i] = {id: i};
}

keys.forEach(k => console.log(o[k].id))
```

Comment: `const o = {};` - это не массив.

Comment: Зачем говорить про массив, но в примере кода использовать объект?

Comment: Чтобы наглядно продемонстрировать, в чём собственно проблема

Comment: я сделал так(обновил), но все равно идет "1", "2"

Comment: Я ошибся, посчитав очевидным неочевидное, простите. Вам нужно отдельно передавать порядок ключей с сервера. Обновил ответ.