# Как отсортировать JSON по ключу android

Tags: android, json

Прилетает такой JSON

```
{
"0": {},
"Server answer": {
    "Request result": "Connected",
    "Error": "false"
},
"Posts": {
    "1": {
        "post_id": "1",
        "post_url": "ftpmgezyklnqd4w9jxr7b3852h06au1isovc",
        "owner_id": "6efb3fdd556db0a860a3bfdba4551cfb",
        "author_id": "6efb3fdd556db0a860a3bfdba4551cfb",
        "post_text": "Об этом не успели рассказать на презентации, а зря.\r\n\r\nВ iPhone 8 установлен модуль Bluetooth версии 5.0. Смартфон с поддержкой такого модуля способен поддерживать соединение на расстоянии более 100 метров. Другими словами, теперь не будет помех во время воспроизведения музыки и неожиданных обрывов связи со смартфоном\r\n\r\nCкорость передачи данных в 4 раза выше по сравнению с версией 4.2, которая как раз используется в «старом» iPhone 7.",
        "images_count": "1",
        "first_image": "https://pp.userapi.com/c841624/v841624004/3a35b/E87ju1hR__A.jpg",
        "second_image": "",
        "third_image": "",
        "post_date": "2017-11-18",
        "author_name": "Pavel Vorobyov",
        "author_avatar": "https://pp.userapi.com/c639127/v639127428/5c93b/FUHZCvNHmd8.jpg"
    },
    "2": {
        "post_id": "2",
        "post_url": "wen3acqjfx2kotzi0myv5slhd4gp6br81u79",
        "owner_id": "6efb3fdd556db0a860a3bfdba4551cfb",
        "author_id": "6efb3fdd556db0a860a3bfdba4551cfb",
        "post_text": "Nomu T18 способен работать в режиме рации\r\n\r\nКомпания Nomu представила новый защищённый смартфон T18, выполненный в ударопрочном корпусе, который не боится продолжительных погружений в воду. Также аппарат имеет ряд уникальных особенностей. Среди них — подключаемая антенна, позволяющая использовать гаджет в качестве полноценной рации, и внешняя камера для съёмки важных моментов.",
        "images_count": "1",
        "first_image": "https://pp.userapi.com/c639921/v639921206/7b432/m7FMveEdibU.jpg",
        "second_image": "",
        "third_image": "",
        "post_date": "2017-11-18",
        "author_name": "Pavel Vorobyov",
        "author_avatar": "https://pp.userapi.com/c639127/v639127428/5c93b/FUHZCvNHmd8.jpg"
    },
    "3": {
        "post_id": "3",
        "post_url": "s5n9uxa08bzofrkvw1hl4ymdg6ce23p7ijtq",
        "owner_id": "6efb3fdd556db0a860a3bfdba4551cfb",
        "author_id": "6efb3fdd556db0a860a3bfdba4551cfb",
        "post_text": "iPhone X вошел в ТОП 25 открытий 2017 года по версии TIME\r\n\r\nЖурнал Time внес iPhone X в перечень из 25 лучших изобретений 2017 года.\r\n\r\nКомпания Apple реализовала в своем текущем флагмане радикальные изменения, добавив функцию идентификации по лицу и изменив дизайн в корне. Руководители корпорации утверждают, что в модели X они достигли того, о чем мечтали еще с 2007 года.\r\n\r\nНесмотря на негативные прогнозы и баснословные цены (от $1000), iPhone X пользуется огромной популярностью в США и других странах с высоким уровнем жизни",
        "images_count": "1",
        "first_image": "https://pp.userapi.com/c834402/v834402206/271a6/Ug0Qs9_VP2Q.jpg",
        "second_image": "",
        "third_image": "",
        "post_date": "2017-11-18",
        "author_name": "Pavel Vorobyov",
        "author_avatar": "https://pp.userapi.com/c639127/v639127428/5c93b/FUHZCvNHmd8.jpg"
    },
    "4": {
        "post_id": "4",
        "post_url": "y428nitg6lfjebd573u9xqvckr10mzwaspoh",
        "owner_id": "6efb3fdd556db0a860a3bfdba4551cfb",
        "author_id": "6efb3fdd556db0a860a3bfdba4551cfb",
        "post_text": "Возрождение дистрибутива Slax \r\n\r\nСпустя четыре с половиной года после прошлого выпуска представлен новый релиз компактного Live-дистрибутива Slax 9.2.1, загрузочный образ которого занимает около 200Мб (amd64, i386). Дистрибутив полностью переработан: если раньше он базировался на Slackware Linux и KDE 4, то новая версия переведена на пакетную базу Debian, пакетный менеджер APT и систему инициализации systemd. ",
        "images_count": "1",
        "first_image": "https://pp.userapi.com/c639631/v639631004/6996a/OrT9F7VR7kU.jpg",
        "second_image": "",
        "third_image": "",
        "post_date": "2017-11-18",
        "author_name": "Pavel Vorobyov",
        "author_avatar": "https://pp.userapi.com/c639127/v639127428/5c93b/FUHZCvNHmd8.jpg"
    }
}
```

}

Таким образом обрабатываю его

```
JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject postsJSON = responseJSON.getJSONObject("Posts");
        Iterator<?> keys = postsJSON.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()){
            Object value = postsJSON.get((String) keys.next());
            if (value != null && value instanceof JSONObject){
                JSONObject postJSON = (JSONObject) value;
                int postID = postJSON.getInt("post_id");
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(postID), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Я достаю post_id, они идут по порядку 1,2,3,4.
Но собственно в чем проблема: в тостах выводится 3,2,1,4.
Хотя по сути должно быть 4,3,2,1. Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выводить записи в JSON по убыванию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745657/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-json-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае объект по ключу `Posts` является словарём с ключами 1,2,3,4. `JSONObject` от `jsonorg` реализует словарь не гарантировав порядок. Т.е. чтение не обязательно будет в том же порядке в котором объекты записывались. Придётся конвертировать в массив (или список) и вручную отсортировать. А затем выводить.

Comment: А если каждый пост доставать отдельным запросом? Но при этом одним подключением.

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Какая задача стоит? Но в любом случае один запрос + одна сортировака лучше чем `n` запросов.

Comment: Вы говорите конвертировать в массив? HashMap использовать?

Comment: Это уже выходит за рамки вопроса о json. Поищите информацию о структурах данных и способах сортировки.

Comment: а вот не создавая массивов и т.п. можно ли как-то JSONobject отсортировать.

Comment: "JSONObject от jsonorg реализует словарь не гарантировав порядок", поэтому ответ - нет.
В объекте который ты используешь лежат объекты, у них нет определённого порядка. Потому что это не имеет смысла.
Твоя проблема "Я достаю post_id, они идут по порядку 1,2,3,4." - в объекте действительно есть объекты по ключам "1","2","3","4". Точно так же могли быть по ключам "a","s","lalal","some_other_key". И ты их получаешь использовав парсер от jsonorg (как и любой другой впринципе), не порядок, а данные. А вот порядок сам устанавливай когда эти объекты получил.